Microsoft Graph webhooks and HTTPS certificates
I'm trying to work with Microsoft Graph notification subscription webhooks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http
I have a test webservice running on my dev machine, using a self-signed certificate.
Microsoft Graph refuses to call this. Error is The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
So I created a test CA, generated a certificate signed by that, and added my test CA to the collection of Certificate Authorities in my Microsoft Entra tenant configuration (Protection->Security Center->Certificate Authorities).
However, using the new certificate gives exactly the same result.
I'm guessing that, unless I use a certificate signed by one of the usual-suspect big-name CAs, Graph is not going to call my webhook ... which makes dev/test work a bit of a pain.
Is there any way around this?

I ended up using a proxy for this.
